# How to blit from a 1D array along a dimension of a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, f#

I have a 2D array, and have computed necessary updates along a given dimension of it using a 1D array (said updates can't be computed in place as earlier calculations would override values needed in later calculations).  I thus want to copy the updates into my 2D array.  The most obvious way to do this would, at first glance, appear to be to use Array slicing and `Array.blit`.

I have tried the approach of extracting the relevant dimension using array slicing, and then blitting across to that, but that doesn't update the values inside the 2D array.  I *think* what is happening is that a new, separate, 1D array is being created when I make the slice, and the values are being blitted into that new array, which of course is dropped a moment later when it goes back out of scope.

I suppose you could say that I was expecting the slicing to return a view into the 2D array which would work for the `blit` function call, but instead the slicing actually returns a new array with the values copied into it (which, thinking about it, is what slicing does otherwise, I believe).

Currently I am using a workaround whereby I create a 2D array, where one of the dimensions is only 1 element wide (thus effectively re-creating a 1D array), and then using `Array2D.blit`.  I would prefer to do it directly though, both because I find this ugly, and moreover because it would be quite useful elsewhere in my program where I can't just declare a 1D array as 2D.

My first approach:

```ml
let srcArray = Array.zeroCreate srcArrayLength
...  // do relevant computation
srcArray.[index] <- result
...  // finish computation
Array.blit srcArray 0 destArray.[index, *] 0 srcArrayLength
```

My current approach:

```ml
let srcArray = Array2D.zeroCreate 1 srcArrayLength
... // do relevant computation
srcArray.[0,index] <- result
...  // finish computation
Array2D.blit srcArray 0 0 destArray index 0 1 srcArrayLength
```

The former approach has no effect on my destination 2D array.  The latter approach works where I use it, but as I said above it isn't nice, and cannot be used in another situation, where I have a jagged 2D array (i.e. `'a[][]`) that I would like to blit across from.

How might I go about achieiving my aim?  I thought of Span/Memory, but it wasn't clear to me if and how they could be used here.  Alternatively, if you can spot a better way to do this that doesn't involve `blit`, I'm all-virtual-ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fairly good solution to this, with the help of someone over in the F# Foundation Slack.  Since nobody else has posted an answer, I'll put this one up.

Both `Array.Copy` (note that that is the [.NET `Array.Copy` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy), not the [F#-specific `Array.copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.copy%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)) and `Buffer.BlockCopy` were suggested to me.  `Array.Copy` still complains about mismatching array types, but `Buffer.BlockCopy` ignores the dimensionality of the supplied array, and merely copies the specified number of bytes from one location to another.  Using this and relying on the fact that 2D arrays are really stored as 1D arrays in row-major order (the same as C, I believe), it is quite possible to overwrite the last dimension of a multi-dimensional array reasonably cleanly.

I updated the code from the 'current approach' in my question to the below:

```
let srcArray = Array.zeroCreate srcArrayLength
... //do relevant computation
srcArray.[index] <- result
... //finish computation
Buffer.BlockCopy(srcArray, 0, destArray, firstDimIndex * lengthOfSecondDim * sizeof<'a>, lengthOfSecondDim * sizeof<'a>
```

Not only does it do the job in a way which I personally find a bit tidier, but it has a side-benefit in that it is noticeably faster than the second approach described in the question - I haven't yet run a benchmark to quantify the difference though.